# Replace a value in a data frame based on a conditional (`if`) statement

Tags: r, recode

In the R data frame coded for below, I would like to replace all of the times that `B` 
appears with `b`.

```
junk <- data.frame(x <- rep(LETTERS[1:4], 3), y <- letters[1:12])
colnames(junk) <- c("nm", "val")
```

this provides:

```
   nm val
1   A   a
2   B   b
3   C   c
4   D   d
5   A   e
6   B   f
7   C   g
8   D   h
9   A   i
10  B   j
11  C   k
12  D   l
```

My initial attempt was to use a `for` and `if` statements like so:

```
for(i in junk$nm) if(i %in% "B") junk$nm <- "b"
```

but as I am sure you can see, this replaces ALL of the values of `junk$nm` with `b`.  I can see why this is doing this but I can't seem to get it to replace only those cases of junk$nm where the original value was `B`.

NOTE:  I managed to solve the problem with `gsub` but in the interest of learning R I still would like to know how to get my original approach to work (if it is possible)

Comment: you might want to add stringsAsFactors = FALSE to the original data.frame construction.

Comment: @jimmyb Why? Factors are useful, and necessary if one is modelling with most of R's modelling code. The correct way of dealing with this is to acknowledge that the data are a factor. If you don't want/need this conversion then you can do as you say. If you do want the factor, then there are easy ways to do the manipulation @Kenny wants to perform.

Comment: So factors used to be more popular because of performance, however, now that strings are immutable and hashed the value of factors is less obvious, as most of the base R functionality will just convert them (albeit with warnings) directly. I think factors result in a significant number of bugs that I find in peoples R code.

Answer (score 255, accepted):

Easier to convert nm to characters and then make the change:

```
junk$nm <- as.character(junk$nm)
junk$nm[junk$nm == "B"] <- "b"
```

EDIT: And if indeed you need to maintain nm as factors, add this in the end:

```
junk$nm <- as.factor(junk$nm)
```

Comment: as.character() makes life so much easier when working with factors. +1

Comment: what if you have multiple columns?

Comment: @diliop :Thanks for that : what if I want to change if junk$nm if it takes values "B", "Y", "Z", ... ?

Answer (score 49):

another useful way to replace values

```
library(plyr)
junk$nm <- revalue(junk$nm, c("B"="b"))
```

Answer (score 30):

Short answer is:

```
junk$nm[junk$nm %in% "B"] <- "b"
```

Take a look at [Index vectors in R Introduction](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Index-vectors) (if you don't read it yet).

---

EDIT. As noticed in comments this solution works for character vectors so fail on your data.

For factor best way is to change level:

```
levels(junk$nm)[levels(junk$nm)=="B"] <- "b"
```

Comment: Short addition: The usage of %in% only really helps if you have a set on the right side, as `c("B","C")`. Doing `junk$nm[junk$nm == "B"]` is the better way.

Comment: Oh, another, important addition: Doing it like this requires first adding the factor level `b` to the factor nm. diliop's version is in fact the better one if you want to work with characters, not factors. (Always think about the type your variables have first!)

Comment: that doesn't work on the data as created by @Kenny because the data are factors. Did you forget a step or do you have the global setting to stop converting characters to factors?

Comment: @Thilo One of the important differences between `%in%` and `==` is `NA` handling: `c(1,2,NA)==1` gives `TRUE, FALSE, NA` but `c(1,2,NA) %in% 1` gives `TRUE, FALSE, FALSE`. And yes I forgot to check if this work :/

Comment: This helped me out as I was specifically looking for how to do this for all values in a character vector. Thanks.

Answer (score 21):

As the data you show are factors, it complicates things a little bit. @diliop's Answer approaches the problem by converting to `nm` to a character variable. To get back to the original factors a further step is required.

An alternative is to manipulate the levels of the factor in place.

```
> lev <- with(junk, levels(nm))
> lev[lev == "B"] <- "b"
> junk2 <- within(junk, levels(nm) <- lev)
> junk2
   nm val
1   A   a
2   b   b
3   C   c
4   D   d
5   A   e
6   b   f
7   C   g
8   D   h
9   A   i
10  b   j
11  C   k
12  D   l
```

That is quite simple and I often forget that there is a replacement function for `levels()`.

**Edit:** As noted by @Seth in the comments, this can be done in a one-liner, without loss of clarity:

```
within(junk, levels(nm)[levels(nm) == "B"] <- "b")
```

Comment: Nice. I didn't know about the replacement function for `levels()`. How about the one liner `junk <- within(junk, levels(nm)[levels(nm)=="B"] <- "b")`?

Comment: @Marek **slaps head** Just goes to show that one shouldn't respond to comments on SO when it is well past ones bedtime. Lets try that again...

Comment: @Seth Indeed - nice. Not sure why I separated the steps? Perhaps for exposition...

Answer (score 12):

The easiest way to do this in one command is to use `which` command and also need not to change the factors into character by doing this:

```
junk$nm[which(junk$nm=="B")]<-"b"
```

Answer (score 5):

You have created a factor variable  in `nm` so you either need to avoid doing so or add an additional level to the factor attributes. You should also avoid using `<-` in the arguments to data.frame()

Option 1:

```
junk <- data.frame(x = rep(LETTERS[1:4], 3), y =letters[1:12], stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
junk$nm[junk$nm == "B"] <- "b"
```

Option 2:

```
levels(junk$nm) <- c(levels(junk$nm), "b")
junk$nm[junk$nm == "B"] <- "b"
junk
```

Comment: @DWin thanks for your input on the problem and the need to consider the type of variable.  I accepted @diliop's answer because it was the first working one.  I know there are a lot of issues over <- vs = but (if it can be answered briefly) why should = be used with `data.frame`?

Comment: You don't need to add `b` as a level, just change the level that is `B` to `b`.

Comment: @KennyPeanuts: the column name is one issue,  Look at `a <- data.frame(x<-1:10)` . Its column name is not `x` but rather a messy `x....1.10`. Better to use data.frame(x=1:10). Then you know what your column name is.

Comment: @Gavin: Easier to add than to replace, and even easier not to make it a factor.

Comment: @Dwin Easier? I disagree - see my Answer for something simple. Adding levels can catch you out, say in modelling with `predict()` which will complain if factors levels in new data don't match those used to fit the model. Cleaner in long run to get the data formatted as you want, properly, than rely on short cuts. I agree it might be easier to not make it a factor, but if it already is one, or needs to be one for some modelling exercise...

Comment: @Gavin: Wouldn't predict error out under _either_ the added or replaced level situation?

Comment: @DWin depends what modelling function you are using. With `lm()` adding or replacing a level works equally well. In say `rpart()` if the levels are not *exactly* the same it will fail. So it does depend on what functions one is using, but we can say that if you get your data structured how you want *before* any modelling is done, then `predict()` will always work.

Comment: @DWin thanks for the clarification on = vs <-, that makse sense. So far I have learned a lot of unanticipated things from the comments... this is great.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ifelse` too, which is very simple to understand

```
junk$val <- ifelse(junk$nm == "B", "b", junk$val)
```

If you still want to do it through `for loop` the correct way of doing it

```
for(i in 1:nrow(junk)){
  if(junk[i, "nm"] == "B"){
    junk[i, "val"] <- "b"
  }
}

junk
> junk
   nm val
1   A   a
2   B   b
3   C   c
4   D   d
5   A   e
6   B   b
7   C   g
8   D   h
9   A   i
10  B   b
11  C   k
12  D   l
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with character variables (note that `stringsAsFactors` is false here) you can use replace:

```
junk <- data.frame(x <- rep(LETTERS[1:4], 3), y <- letters[1:12], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
colnames(junk) <- c("nm", "val")

junk$nm <- replace(junk$nm, junk$nm == "B", "b")
junk
#    nm val
# 1   A   a
# 2   b   b
# 3   C   c
# 4   D   d
# ...
```

Comment: This works for all variable types. I just used it to insert NA at certain indices in an integer vector.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue, you can also do the same thing for each columns,

```
 fix_junk <- function(x){
      #x <- as.character(x)
      x[x == "B"] <- "b"
      x
    }
    junk[] <- lapply(junk, fix_junk); junk # junk[] to get a data frame rather than a list
    junk[1:3] <- lapply(junk[1:3], fix_junk); junk
```

Answer (score 0):

```
stata.replace<-function(data,replacevar,replacevalue,ifs) {
  ifs=parse(text=ifs)
  yy=as.numeric(eval(ifs,data,parent.frame()))
  x=sum(yy)
  data=cbind(data,yy)
  data[yy==1,replacevar]=replacevalue
  message=noquote(paste0(x, " replacement are made"))
  print(message)
  return(data[,1:(ncol(data)-1)])
}
```

Call this function using below line.

```
d=stata.replace(d,"under20",1,"age<20")
```