# Changing values in list if that value meets criteria in R

Tags: r

I have a set of data that I am importing from a csv

```
info <- read.csv("test.csv")
```

here is an example of what it would look like

```
  name   type   purchase
1 mark   new    yes
2 steve  old    no
3 jim    old    yes
4 bill   new    yes
```

**What I want to do:**

I want to loop through the `purchase` column and change all the `yes`'s to True & `no`'s to be False. Then loop through the `type` column and change all the `old`'s to `customer`.

I've tried to mess with all the different apply's and couldnt get it to work. Also Ive tried a bunch of the methods in this thread [Replace a value in a data frame based on a conditional (`if`) statement in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824173/replace-a-value-in-a-data-frame-based-on-a-conditional-if-statement-in-r) but still no luck.

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated!

Thanks,
Nico

Comment: To improve your quality of learning, please show what you have tried that didn't work. Others might be able to point you in the right direction to fix your code rather than just answering your question for you. Having offered an answer to your question, I tried the answers at the linked question and had no problem applying them to your situation.

Comment: Thanks and will do in the future. I was trying all the solutions with levels() and it was giving me weird errors but next time will be more thorough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an approach using `within`, basic character substitution, and basic tests for character equivalence.

```
within(mydf, {
  type <- gsub("old", "customer", type)
  purchase <- purchase == "yes"
})
#    name     type purchase
# 1  mark      new     TRUE
# 2 steve customer    FALSE
# 3   jim customer     TRUE
# 4  bill      new     TRUE
```

I've used `gsub` to replace "type", but there are other approaches that can be taken (eg `factor`, `ifelse`, and so on).