# Copy a value from another variable if statement is true

Tags: r, variables

I have a small problem, or acctually kind of large.
I have a dataset with 3 variables that I use atm, lets call them var1, var2 and var3.
In total I have over 3000 observations with NA values in every variable.

var1=age_1, var2=Yes/No and var3=age_2

What I want to do is if var2="Yes" the value from var1 should be coopied into var3.
I have done it in this way:

```
var3[var2=="Yes"]<-var1
```

but I get the error message:

```
Error in var3[var2 == "Yes"] <-var1 :
```

NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments

Someone has a quick solution how I can solve this?

Comment: var3 <- ifelse(test = (var2 == 'YES'), var1, var3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try

```
var3 <- ifelse(var2 == "Yes", var1, var3)
```

Answer (score 2):

The error sounds like you have `NA` values in `var2`. You can test to see if `sum(is.na(var))>0` So if you have missing values R doesn't want to guess if missing is the same as "Yes" or "No" so you get the error.

Also, by only indexing one side of the assignment, you're not necessarily matching up values across rows. So even in you fix your NA values, you'd likley get the `number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length` error.

One trick is to use `which` to remove `NA` values form the logical indexes and transform them into numeric indices. Then once you know the rows you want to replace, you can use the same index on both sides of the assignment.

```
var1 <- c(10, 20, 30)
var2 <- c("No", "Yes", "No")
var3 <- c(100, 200, 3000)

idx <- which(var2=="Yes")
var3[idx] <- var1[idx]

var3
# [1]  100   20 3000
```

or you can use the `ifelse` function which makes all these steps much easier

```
var3<-ifelse(var2=="Yes", var1, var3)
```

Comment: Why the heck this answer (OP's command, in effect) doesn't work? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824173/replace-a-value-in-a-data-frame-based-on-a-conditional-if-statement It seems brackets can only be used to replace to a fixed number, not for a variable

Comment: @luchonacho I'm not sure which answer you are referring to specifically. If you meant this one, I've added some sample data that you can use to run and verify it works.

Comment: If you are talking about the `if(i %in% "B") junk$nm <- "b"` part, that's because once that `if` statement is true once, then `junk$nm <- "b"` runs which assigned "b" to every value in that column. That statement has no idea what the "current" row is. It doesn't use `i`

Comment: Sorry. i meant the one on the link I shared. Essentially, `var3[var2=="Yes"]<-var1`. I get message that replacement has different number of rows than data.

Comment: @luchonacho That's because you're not indexing `var1` at all. If all vectors are the same length, it should look like `var3[var2=="Yes"]<-var1[var2=="Yes"]`

Comment: got it. Thanks!