# Capping each member in an r array

Tags: arrays, r, vector, limit

I'm new to R and I have losses data:

```
losses=c(25,250,5,17,2,195,12,8,75,5,50,1);
```

How to cap each member of the list at 150? Namely how to perform `min(150,x)` for each member of the list?

Then I want to cap all losses at 'amount of insurance' array:

```
aoi=c(150,250,100,125,300,200,80,250,100,350,500,120)
```

Comment: then I want to cap all losses at 'amount of insurance' aoi=c(150,250,100,125,300,200,80,250,100,350,500,120) array. Thanks.

Comment: have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824173/replace-a-value-in-a-data-frame-based-on-a-conditional-if-statement-in-r

Comment: i.e. losses[losses >= 150] <- 150

Comment: thank you Alex for the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See `?pmin`, or parallel minima calculation:

```
pmin(150,losses)
#[1]  25 150   5  17   2 150  12   8  75   5  50   1
```

If you need to do this multiple times, it would be beneficial to collect your variables in a `data.frame` or `list`. E.g.:

```
dat <- data.frame(losses,aoi)
data.frame(Map(pmin,dat,150))

#   losses aoi
#1      25 150
#2     150 150
#3       5 100
#etc...
```

Comment: I always seem to get pmin and pmax confused. `pmin` is for setting a maximum and `pmax` is for setting a minimum.

Comment: @BondedDust - the OP's description of what they want to do is actually a neat definition of `pmin` - "_perform min(150,x) for each member of the list?_" - which could be transferred straight to `sapply(losses, function(x) min(150,x) )`

Comment: I wasn't saying this question confused me, only that I confuse myself when I'm at the keyboard when I think ... now I need to set a "max".

Comment: Superb, does exactly what is needed with minimum fuss and bother.