# How to replace Ones with Zeros and Zeros with Ones in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, replace

I have a dataframe df. I would like to replace all zeros with ones and all ones with zeros in the dataframe. Or in general, if I have to find some value (like one) and replace the value with something else, what's the best approach?

```
  a b
1 1 0
2 0 1
3 1 0
4 0 0
```

Comment: Just subtract 1 from the whole dataframe? `1 - df` (not sure how you do it with R :p)

Comment: `abs(df - 1)` in R. @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace a value in a data frame based on a conditional (\`if\`) statement in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824173/replace-a-value-in-a-data-frame-based-on-a-conditional-if-statement-in-r) Or more generally [Dictionary style replace multiple items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7547597/dictionary-style-replace-multiple-items)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A code golf would be to negate the dataset and use `+`

```
+(!df)
#  a b
#1 0 1
#2 1 0
#3 0 1
#4 1 1
```

Comment: @ thanks, but in a general case, if I have to replace all zeros with a value (for example, 6) what to do in this case?

Comment: @yome What about the `1s`?  use `replace(df, !df, 6)`

Comment: 1s with another specific value lets say 5?

Comment: @yome  If you have many values to replace, you could use `case_when` or `if_else`  one option in `dplyr` would be `df %>% mutate_all(funs(case_when(.==1~5L, .==0 ~ 6L, TRUE ~.)))` or in `base R`, `lapply(df, function(x) ifelse(x == 1, 5, ifelse(x == 0, 6, x)))` It depends on how many values you want to replace.  A general approach would be key/value pair and then do the replacement for many values

Comment: can you help answer this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48019176/change-color-of-the-values-in-heatmap-in-highcharter-r-package

Answer (score 2):

```
mydata=data.frame(a=c(1,0,1,0),b=c(0,1,0,0));
psych::reverse.code(c(-1,-1),mydata)
```