# Replace a value in a data frame based on a conditional statement

Tags: r

I have a question very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824173/replace-a-value-in-a-data-frame-based-on-a-conditional-if-statement) question

```
 country                      continent
   <chr>                        <chr>    
 1 Taiwan                       Asia     
 2 New Zealand                  Oceania  
 3 Bulgaria                     Europe   
 4 Bahamas                      Americas 
 5 Serbia                       Europe   
 6 Tajikistan                   Asia     
 7 Southern Sub-Saharan Africa  NA       
 8 Cameroon                     Africa   
 9 Indonesia                    Asia     
10 Democratic Republic of Congo Africa
```

How do I use a function/write a loop so that when the country is "Bahamas" that it converts the continent so that it now says South America?

The page that I linked was the closest answer I could find but it differed from my question because I am trying to manipulate one column based on the values in a different column.

I tried using ifelse() but that did not work:

```
gm %>%
  ifelse(country == "Bahamas", continent == "S America", continent)
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `mutate`:

```
library(dplyr)
gm %>%
  mutate(continent = ifelse(country == "Bahamas", "S America", continent))
```

Comment: Arrrgh.  It's always something really small that brings my projects to a halt.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

**This works:**

```
gm[,'continent'][gm[,'country'] == "Bahamas"] <- "South America"
```

You might get a warning message like this if "South America" is not already in the dataframe:

```
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, gm[, "country"] == "Bahamas", value = c(2L,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

This means you need to **add the level first**, you are trying to issue a level which doesn't exist:

```
levels(gm$continent) <- c(levels(gm$continent), "South America")
gm[,'continent'][gm[,'country'] == "Bahamas"] <- "South America"
```

*(run time on this approach [5M entries in a dataframe, 10 repeated measures] was 4x faster than the `dplyr` method)*

Comment: I find that learning how to solve problems without using _tidyverse_ packages helps me learn a lot more about how R works.  Thank you!

Comment: I should spend some time familiarising myself with tidyverse - it's very fashionable at the moment - but sometimes feels like people assume it's better than any other option, in my experience it's situation dependent and other approaches can often out perform tidyverse.

Comment: I totally agree with you.  Since I am a noob, initially focusing on the Tidyverse gives me a set of tools that would be more difficult to learn with Base R functionality.