# Category of variable didn't change in R

Tags: r

I want rename a category in a variable as shown here
[Replace a value in a data frame based on a conditional (`if`) statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824173/replace-a-value-in-a-data-frame-based-on-a-conditional-if-statement)

The values of `itog$GOODS_NAME` are:

```
МАКФА макар УЛИТКИ 450г
```

When I change one of them like this:

```
itog$GOODS_NAME[itog$GOODS_NAME == "макар"] <- "макароны"
```

The values of `itog$GOODS_NAME` should be:

```
МАКФА макароны УЛИТКИ 450г`
```

But instead they are unchanged:

```
itog$GOODS_NAME

МАКФА макар УЛИТКИ 450г
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that your variable itog$GOODS_NAME is a factor. You can check that with `class(itog$GOODS_NAME)`. When it is a factor, you have to convert it to a character.

```
itog = data.frame(GOODS_NAME = c("МАКФА", "макар", "УЛИТКИ", "450г"))
itog$GOODS_NAME = as.character(itog$GOODS_NAME)
itog$GOODS_NAME[itog$GOODS_NAME=="макар"] = "макароны"
itog$GOODS_NAME
```

Output:

```
"МАКФА"    "макароны" "УЛИТКИ"   "450г"
```